# Angular2 RxJs map http response

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs

I have api which returns list of photos object, which I want to iterate using subscribe().. not all at once, **but one by one**..

```
http.get('photos.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
```

Which functions (map, flatmap...) can I use to convert response into multiple array, so when using subscribe, it will iterate one by one.. and not all response at once.

json [example file](http://www.pgbovine.net/photos/json-files/boston.json)

Comment: You want to iterate the images, right?

Comment: Kind of yes, but not by passing complete images to angular.. but make them obversable.. so we can apply more filters, before iterating over them.

Comment: You already have the answer. You just have to import it from `rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap` (flatMap is an alias of mergeMap), see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/src/add/operator/mergeMap.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flatmap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) will do it, if you create an Observable out of the resulting array.

`yourPhotosArray.flatMap(photos => Observable.from(photos))`

will convert your array of photos into Observable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
http.get('photos.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .flatMap((array, index) => array)
  .filter(photo => 600 <= photo.height)
  .subscribe(photo => console.log(photo))
```